# Exclude zero values from a ggplot barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, zero

does anyone know if it is possible to exclude zero values from a barplot in ggplot?

I have a dataset that contains proportions as follows:

```
 X5employf       prop X5employff
1   increase 0.02272727           
2   increase 0.59090909          1
3   increase 0.02272727   1  and 8
4   increase 0.02272727          2
5   increase 0.34090909          3
6   increase 0.00000000          4
7   increase 0.00000000          5
8   increase 0.00000000          6
9   increase 0.00000000    6 and 7
10  increase 0.00000000   6 and 7 
11  increase 0.00000000          7
12  increase 0.00000000          8
13  decrease 0.00000000           
14  decrease 0.00000000          1
15  decrease 0.00000000   1  and 8
16  decrease 0.00000000          2
17  decrease 0.00000000          3
18  decrease 0.10000000          4
19  decrease 0.50000000          5
20  decrease 0.20000000          6
21  decrease 0.00000000    6 and 7
22  decrease 0.00000000   6 and 7 
23  decrease 0.10000000          7
24  decrease 0.10000000          8
25      same 0.00000000           
26      same 0.00000000          1
27      same 0.00000000   1  and 8
28      same 0.00000000          2
29      same 0.00000000          3
30      same 0.21052632          4
31      same 0.31578947          5
32      same 0.26315789          6
33      same 0.15789474    6 and 7
34      same 0.00000000   6 and 7 
35      same 0.05263158          7
36      same 0.00000000          8
```

as you can see in the 'prop' column there are a lot of zero values. I am producing a facetted bar plot with 'X5employf' column as the facet. But because of the zero values I end up with a lot of empty space on my plot(see below). Is there a way of forcing ggplot to not plot the zero values? Its not the case of dropping unused factors as these are not NA values but 0s. Any ideas??!

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 15):

For your plot, simply use `which` to specify that you only want to use the subset of the dataframe containing non-zero proportions. This way you don't have to modify your original dataframe. Then, specify "free_x" in your `scales` argument within `facet_grid` to get rid of your empty space in your faceted plot.

```
plot <- ggplot(df[which(df$prop>0),], aes(X5employff, prop)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=X5employff, stat="identity")) +
  facet_grid( ~ X5employf, scales="free_x") +
  theme_bw()
plot
```

[image]

Note that I replaced the blank fields with "blank" for the sake of quick import into R from Excel.

Comment: Also, [the answer to this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888456/why-this-facet-grid-doesnt-delete-columns) shows a slightly different way to do this, by adding `drop=TRUE` within the `aes` argument inside `ggplot()`

Comment: thanks sc_evans, that's what I wanted. still trying to get my head around R syntax! Do you know if ggplot will calculate the proportions for me first? Previously I had to use ddply to summarise my data before I plotted it?!?

Comment: I'd have to see what your original dataframe looks like, but what I usually do is calculate the proportion inside `aes()`. So, something like `ggplot(data, aes(x, y=[value/sum(values)]))`. Anyway, is this what you're asking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057081/ddply-summarise-proportional-count)?

Comment: Is there a general workaround? I'm using a variable to plot and hence can't subset the dataframe in before.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure whether or not there is a way to set ignored values in `ggplot`. However you could consider simply recoding 0's to NA:

```
df[df$prop == 0] <- NA
```