# ddply summarise proportional count

Tags: r, plyr

I am having some trouble using the ddply function from the plyr package. I am trying to summarise the following data with counts and proportions within each group. Here's my data:

```
    structure(list(X5employf = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("increase", "decrease", "same"), class = "factor"), 
    X5employff = structure(c(2L, 6L, NA, 2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 
    2L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 
    7L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
    2L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 5L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
    13L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 8L, 5L), .Label = c("", "1", "1  and 8", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "6 and 7", "6 and 7 ", "7", "8", 
    "1 and 8"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X5employf", "X5employff"
), row.names = c(NA, 73L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here's my call using ddply:

```
ddply(kano_final, .(X5employf, X5employff), summarise, n=length(X5employff), prop=(n/sum(n))*100)
```

This gives me the counts of each instance of `X5employff` correctly, but but seems as though the proportion is being calculated across each row and not within each level of the factor `X5employf` as follows:

```
   X5employf X5employff  n prop
1   increase          1 26  100
2   increase          2  1  100
3   increase          3 15  100
4   increase    1 and 8  1  100
5   increase       <NA>  1  100
6   decrease          4  1  100
7   decrease          5  5  100
8   decrease          6  2  100
9   decrease          7  1  100
10  decrease          8  1  100
11      same          4  4  100
12      same          5  6  100
13      same          6  5  100
14      same    6 and 7  3  100
15      same          7  1  100
```

When manually calculating the proportions within each group I get this:

```
   X5employf X5employff  n prop
1   increase          1 26  59.09
2   increase          2  1  2.27
3   increase          3 15  34.09
4   increase    1 and 8  1  2.27
5   increase       <NA>  1  2.27
6   decrease          4  1  10.00
7   decrease          5  5  50.00
8   decrease          6  2  20.00
9   decrease          7  1  10.00
10  decrease          8  1  10.00
11      same          4  4  21.05
12      same          5  6  31.57
13      same          6  5  26.31
14      same    6 and 7  3  15.78
15      same          7  1  5.26
```

As you can see the sum of proportions in each level of factor X5employf equals 100.

I know this is probably ridiculously simple, but I can't seem to get my head around it despite reading all sorts of similar posts. Can anyone help with this and my understanding of how the summarise function works?!

Many, many thanks

Marty

Comment: it turns out that `sum(n)` is not being computed as desired

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do it in one `ddply` call because what gets passed to each `summarize` call is a subset of your data for a specific combination of your group variables. At this lowest level, you do not have access to that intermediate level `sum(n)`. Instead, do it in two steps:

```
kano_final <- ddply(kano_final, .(X5employf), transform,
                    sum.n = length(X5employf))

ddply(kano_final, .(X5employf, X5employff), summarise, 
      n = length(X5employff), prop = n / sum.n[1] * 100)
```

---

**Edit**: using a single `ddply` call and using `table` as you hinted towards:

```
ddply(kano_final, .(X5employf), summarise,
      n          = Filter(function(x) x > 0, table(X5employff, useNA = "ifany")),
      prop       = 100* prop.table(n),
      X5employff = names(n))
```

Comment: thanks flodel, that's exactly what I wanted. Is there anyway of combining this into a single call? I'm trying to summarise a fairly large dataset and am trying to get to a point where I can write a script for this so in each case I just have to enter a grouped variable and a 'measured' variable a little like this example for calculating the confidence interval of groups within a dataset: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Summarizing_data/

Comment: oh and still not entirely sure of the difference between 'transform' and 'summarise'!?

Comment: `transform` adds to every row of your data (like the base `ave` function does), while `summarize` will aggregate your data (like the base `aggregate` function does).

Answer (score 1):

I'd add here an example with dplyr which makes it quite easily in one step, with a short-code and easy-to-read syntax.

d is your data.frame

```
library(dplyr)
d%.%
  dplyr:::group_by(X5employf, X5employff) %.%
  dplyr:::summarise(n = length(X5employff)) %.%
  dplyr:::mutate(ngr = sum(n)) %.% 
  dplyr:::mutate(prop = n/ngr*100)
```

will result in

```
Source: local data frame [15 x 5]
Groups: X5employf

   X5employf X5employff  n ngr      prop
1   increase          1 26  44 59.090909
2   increase          2  1  44  2.272727
3   increase          3 15  44 34.090909
4   increase    1 and 8  1  44  2.272727
5   increase         NA  1  44  2.272727
6   decrease          4  1  10 10.000000
7   decrease          5  5  10 50.000000
8   decrease          6  2  10 20.000000
9   decrease          7  1  10 10.000000
10  decrease          8  1  10 10.000000
11      same          4  4  19 21.052632
12      same          5  6  19 31.578947
13      same          6  5  19 26.315789
14      same    6 and 7  3  19 15.789474
15      same          7  1  19  5.263158
```

Answer (score 0):

What you apparently want to do is to find out the proportions of X5employff for every value of X5employf. However, you don't tell ddply that X5employf and X5employff are different; to ddply, these two variables are just two variables to split up the data. Also, since there is one observation per line, i.e. count = 1 for every line of the data, the length of each (X5employf, X5employff) combination equals the sum of each (X5employf, X5employff) combination.

The simplest "plyr way" to solve your problem that I can think of is the following:

```
result <- ddply(kano_final, .(X5employf, X5employff), summarise, n=length(X5employff), drop=FALSE)
n <- result$n
n2 <- ddply(kano_final, .(X5employf), summarise, n=length(X5employff))$n
result <- data.frame(result, prop=n/rep(n2, each=13)*100)
```

You can also use good old xtabs:

```
a <- xtabs(~X5employf + X5employff, kano_final)
b <- xtabs(~X5employf, kano_final)
a/matrix(b, nrow=3, ncol=ncol(a))
```

Comment: what is the difference between your plyr solution and @flodel?

Comment: One difference I see is that I don't use a hardcoded `each = 13`. That won't generalize well...

Comment: Thanks both, this is getting me much closer to understanding what's going on. I found this which which seems even simpler, but I don't really understand what's happening: `df.new<-ddply(kano_final,.(X5employf),summarise,
              prop=prop.table(table(X5employff)),
              X5employff=names(table(X5employff)))` It seems to work though...but doesn't add a 'count' column. I should have mentioned the reason behind all this is so that I can plot either a frequency count or frequency percentage bar plot of the results using ggplot2 or similar...